# Is there a way to integrate Phaser with a web app written in asp.net MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, phaser-framework

I have a game web app written in ASP.net MVC - and I would like know if it's possible to integrate the Phaser game engine with asp.net? If yes - can someone point me to an online tutorial or resource that could help me out?

Comment: I've updated tags, in particular please confirm that phaser one is correct (it is unlikely previous one was related to your question as it was about some Java framework).

Comment: Note that in current state post is too broad or search for tutorials... It is unlikely to be answered in small concrete answer (short of "yes, you can use whatever JavaScript library you want").

Answer (score 3):

Phaser is a JavaScript framework used to create games, while ASP.NET MVC is a server-side web application framework.

Create a new view to display your game, and then use the official [Making your first Phaser game](http://phaser.io/tutorials/making-your-first-phaser-game) tutorial to learn how to get started with Phaser.

Since you're using ASP.NET MVC, there's of course no issue with putting the relevant code in your view, instead of creating a HTML file.